# Firefox automatically switching to https

Tags: firefox, https

I am using firefox 14 and lately, I have been observing this weird problem with my firefox. Everytime I put an address in address bar and hit return, https version of the site opens. This has no problem to me but some of my the sites which do not support https can not be opened without typing full http:// followed by the site .

I am not using https enabling extension. No extensions were changed when this problem popped up.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the website automatically forwarding you to use https?

Comment: Is this happening for all websites or some specific???

Comment: @KenWhite ok.no problem mate :)

Comment: Can you try to open firefox in safe mode? From command prompt, try EITHER *firefox -safe-mode* or *"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -safe-mode* or *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -safe-mode* and see if the problem persists. Does it happen to IE as well?

Comment: It can be turned off: http://superuser.com/questions/554399/are-web-browsers-automatically-using-https-when-available/554400#554400

Answer (score -1):

Yes! Firefox have decided to implemented https by default with firefox 14. Check out the following links:

[Information week](http://www.informationweek.com/security/privacy/firefox-takes-privacy-lead-with-https-by/232602977)
[Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2012/07/17/firefox-14-browser-google-search-https/)

Comment: Yes, but this covers only google's sites.Not whole internet.